# how to use OCR for image scanning in iOS?

Tags: iphone

"I am working on one project , In which I want to read the text and numbers from the images from camera, 
What I am looking for :
1) OCR library which can be useful for IOS and Andriod app.
2) Have good accuracy of reading OCR "

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one I know with very good accuracy and community to help.

[Tessaract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

You can try some tools that will make it easy for integration in Android and iOS

Here is its tool for android : [Tesseract for android](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)

and here is its tool for iOS: [Tesseract for iOS](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)